# How can I search for a contact by the date it was created?

Tags: contacts

How can I search for a contact by the date it was created? I forget her name!

Comment: OS X or iOS?  I.e. Your Mac or iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

You did not state what OS X or iOS version and my reply is base on my system, MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013 running OS X 10.8.5, and I don't believe you can as the date/time stamp, both created and modified, on the datastore for Contacts is constantly changing each time Contacts is opened.

You can look at `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Metadata` and see the date/time stamp gets updated on all of them and checking Get Info you'll see the date/time stamp for both created and modified are the same. (At least it is on my Mac.) If not this is the only place I see where you might be able to sort by date/time stamp, assuming it's not changing constantly like on my system.

Also looking at the contents of the `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb` file, the SQL Database used by Contacts, there is no field that holds a date/time stamp.

So, if you can't remember the persons name and date/time stamps are changing constantly you'll have to scroll through all your Contacts until you can find it by process of elimination against those you remember.

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly can.

Go to your Desktop and press ***Command* + *Shift* + *G***, paste this:

> ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources

...and then click *Go*.

You will find that there are folders with very long names. In each of these folders there will be a folder called *Metadata*, in which you will find those contact files.

You can temporarily create a folder on your Desktop, move each and every contact to the new folder and sort them.

To do the sorting, right-click where it says *Name*, *Date Modified*, *Size*, *etc...* and select *Date Created*. Now, in the same sorting menu, click *Date Created* (which was your desired sorting).

Now to actually see them sorted in that way, select the topmost contact and press space. Now press the down arrow and the contacts will be viewed as newest (top) to oldest (bottom).

Once you're done with the sorting, in the top menu choose and click *Undo Move of "..."* until the words "Move of" are gone (i.e. indicates that all the moving that you did has been undone).

(Just a note, open the contacts app and make sure the contacts are all back where they should be.)

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013 running OS X 10.8.5 and I can tell you that it is not possible to do what the OP asks on my system for the reasons I outlined in my answer.  Nor does it have the `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources` folder you've mentioned.  Additionally, why on earth would I choose to move files as you've suggested when making a copy is the proper thing to do, if even need be. Unfortunately Linda did not state what OS X or iOS version so while what I said is the correct answer under OS X 10.8.5 it may not be under a different version.

Comment: @user3439894 Fair enough, copying would be just fine. I just assumed that copying a file changed its Date Created data. I just checked and found my assumption to be wrong.
As for the directory that I mentioned, OS X most certainly does have it. I'm running 10.9.5 on a late 2013 15" MBP and I tested everything that I wrote above before writing it. It's easier done than said (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yes, easier done then said makes sense. The `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources` doesn't exist under 10.8.5 and I just checked under 10.10.4 and it too doesn't exist. Unfortunately when the User doesn't provide appropriate information it can sometimes be difficult to give an answer that works under all versions.

Comment: Absolutely, at least mentioning the OS would point us in the right direction. As for the directory, I don't know why it isn't showing up for you. Are you sure you haven't overlooked a detail or two? I'm totally confused. Try and navigate to the _Sources_ folder in Terminal using the root user, maybe it isn't being displayed, or idk, I'm just thinking of explanations. Maybe you're not using iCloud contacts, while I am. It's a bugging thought that something works for me but not for the preceding nor the succeeding version of the same OS. Let me know (if possible) when you find it.

Comment: I'm not using iCloud so that may be why it doesn't exist on my system.